# Unity Input Touch issue

Tags: input, touch

Could you please advise how i would go about using the input touch function in Unity to make an object changes its x direction every time the user tap on the screen. For example, for 2d setting game, an object is moving forward (to the right) in the x position, if the user tap then the object would move backward in the x position (to the left). Sorry no code is produced.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as your name "tony" :)

What you can do is to make a simple script which'd move your object to left and right. And on screen touch you can easily change its direction by just -1 multiplication.

Simple script that you can attach to your object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    float _limit = 5;

    // 1 for right and -1 for left.
    float _direction = 1;

    // You can call it as speed
    float _speed = 0.01f;


    void Start ()
    {

    }

    void Update ()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x + _direction, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), _speed);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
            _direction *= -1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Hamza, haha thanks for your input:). I will give that a try a let you know.

Comment: Hi Hamza, it works well, thanks a lot for your help:).

Comment: Hi tony, If it works well then kindly mark it as answer so other people may know that it is working one